# Plus symbol in constraint layout when setting constraints

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I am seeing a pattern followed in many project and I would like to know more about it.
In `ConstraintLayout` while setting constraints, I can see this pattern.

`app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/textView"`

If you see above, textview is already created and is used here to set constraints. Then why is there a + symbol before `id`. And surprisingly, this doesn't cause any issue as far as I observed.
My questions are:

1. Does this cause any problem? If yes, what problem?
2. Google examples don't follow this pattern. Then how come many other project follow this pattern? Suggested/Generated code from android studio doens't have the + symbol. Does any other IDE include + symbol in the suggestions? Is this caused by IDE?
3. Adding + symbol before `id` creates a new `id` but not in this case? Did Google specifically handle this case?

Answer (score 0):

The + creates a new id if it doesn't already exist. Otherwise it uses the same id.

When dealing with XML layouts it can be annoying to remove and readd the + everytime you change your XML and move things around. Without the + your app might crash if you're referencing an ID before it is created.
So just using the + all the time simplifies things.